# how to display the comments on the same page? cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am starting to learn PHP framework, particulary cakephp. I know how to insert into database, but I am curious about displaying the entries on the same page. I don't want to reload or redirect the page just to display the results.

I have only three four fields in the database. id, name, email, and the date. I have used the same validation in the model page.

Controllers:

```
<?php
function index(){
 if($this->request->is('Post')){
   $this->Save->save(data);
 }
 //display the entries from the database
 $this->set('saves', $this->Save->find('all'));
}
?>
```

Index.ctp:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Save');
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('class'=>'name', 'required' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class'=>'email',  'required' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('message', array( 'required' => true)); 
echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array('formnovalidate' => true));

//i want to display the entries here
foreach($saves as $row){
  echo $row['Save']['name'];
  echo $row['Save']['comment']; 
}
?>
```

The problem is that , it affects the textarea. It reduces the size to half. Need help. thanks a lot. I am new to cakephp and I have been googling about it, but have not find the any results. Thanks

Comment: one thing that make me wonder is how come you can use $save in the view while you set it as $saves in the controller.

Comment: it is a typo, but it is not really the issue.

Comment: if u want the newly added row to also be displayed, u need to use ajax refresh..

Comment: You seem to have two problems, one is the textarea is reduces by half, and the other that you don't want to reload the page to add a new entry. Is that so or did I misunderstood the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it seems that your problem is more CSS issue than CakePHP issue. I don't think printing the data will cut the field into half.

Try put  after echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array('formnovalidate' => true)); because the submit method does not include  afterwards.

You can this $this->Form->end if you don't want to add the form closing tag manually.